# Solving trailing slash problem for a given setup

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Considering the following rules, how can I rewrite them in order have a trailing slash? I have to mention that I can only edit the .htaccess file, so I have no access to modify the URLs in the website.

```
RewriteRule ^artists/(.*)-p(.*)$ /artists.php?l=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^artists/(.*)$ /artists.php?l=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lyrics/(.*)/(.*)$ /artists-albums.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lyrics/(.*)$ /artists-details.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^p-(.*)-(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1&q=$2 [QSA,L]
```

So, if someone is looking up `/lyrics/abba` it has to automatically redirect to `/lyrics/abba/`.

Answer (score 0):

Add another rule to rewrite things that don't end in a slash, before the other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

(I may have borked the exact regex on that one, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in front of your other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $0 !.*\.php$
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```

But you should also modify your existing rules by replacing `.*` with at least `.+` or better `[^/]+`:

```
RewriteRule ^artists/([^/-]+)-p([^/]+)$ /artists.php?l=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^artists/([^/]+)$ /artists.php?l=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lyrics/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /artists-albums.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lyrics/([^/]+)$ /artists-details.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^p-([^/-]+)-([^/]+)$ /index.php?p=$1&q=$2 [QSA,L]
```

If possible you should use even more specific pattern (`[0-9]+` for numbers, `[1-9][0-9]*` for numbers without 0, etc.).

Comment: It's almost what I want, but I have some rules for which I don't want an ending slash. For example this one: RewriteRule ^lyrics/(.*)/(.*).php /artists-lyrics.php?a=$1&c=$2 [QSA,L]

Also, for this rule RewriteRule ^artists/(.*)$ /artists.php?l=$1 [QSA,L] when it gets the value of "l" in PHP it has the ending slash. Like if the value is "a", in PHP it will be "a/".

Comment: Then just put the rewrite rule for the trailing slash *after* the rules you don't want affected, and *before* the rules you do.

Comment: @Gumbo, I made all the changes above, but now it redirects to some 404.shtml saying "The page isn't redirecting properly".